# Python Pandas: Efficiently assign values to a slice

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `next_train` with weekly data for many players (80,000 players observed through 4 weeks, total of 320,000 observations) and a dictionary `players` containing a binary variable for some of the players (say 10,000). I want to add this binary variable to the dataframe `next_train` (if a player is not in the dictionary `players`, I set the variable equal to zero). This is how I'm doing it:

```
next_train = pd.read_csv()
# ... calculate dictionary 'players' ...
next_train['variable'] = 0
for player in players:
    next_train.loc[next_train['id_of_player'] == player, 'variable'] = players[player]
```

However the `for` loop takes ages to complete, and I don't understand why. It looks like the task is to perform binary search for the value `player` in my dataframe for 10,000 times (size of the `players` dictionary), but the execution time is several minutes. Is there any efficient way to do this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `map` instead of slicing, that will be way faster:

```
next_train['variable'] = next_train.id_of_player.map(players)
```

As you want 0 in the other rows, you can then use `fillna`:

```
next_train.variable.fillna(0,inplace = True)
```

Moreover, if your dictionnary only contains boolean values, you might want to redefine the type of `variable` column to take less space. So you end with this piece of code:

```
next_train['variable'] = next_train.id_of_player.map(players).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` and `fillna`:

```
next_train['variable'] = next_train['id_of_player'].map(players).fillna(0)
```

This creates a new column by applying the dictionary on the player ids and then fills all empty values with 0.